# White screen of death on dynamic sql php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am learning php creation of Web pages with MySQL.
wanted to to run the script, but I fails.
I get white screen of death.
Can you look at the code and tell me what to do and in which direction I should go.
thanks for your time.

```
<?php
include 'include.php';
// PHP Class bracket
// Bracket builder for GotGames
// Author Benjamin Thomas
// October 2009
class bracket {
//Bring In Database Details From Include.PHP
var $username = DB_USER;
var $password = DB_PASS;
var $database = DB_NAME;
//Init Class Variables
var $tournament_name;
var $tournament_size;
var $tournament_format;
var $tournament_id;
var $result_servers;
var $result_stvs;
var $result_matches;
var $result_teams;
//*************************************************************************************
// schedule bracket
// Input - The tournament ID used to identify which tournament we are scheduling for
// Operation - This constructor reads the required information from the     databas and assigns the following class values:
// tournament_name;
// tournament_size;
// tournament_format;
// tournament_id;
// result_servers;
// result_stvs;
// result_matches;
// result_teams;
//*************************************************************************************
function bracket($tourn_id) {
//Save the Tournament ID
$this->tournament_id = $tourn_id;
//Collect All Required Information To Draw a Bracket
mysql_connect('localhost',$this->username,$this->password);
@mysql_select_db($this->database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tms_tournament WHERE id = ".$tourn_id;
$result_tournament = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_tournament);
$this->tournament_name = $row['name'];
$this->tournament_size = $row['size'];
$this->tournament_format = $row['format'];
mysql_free_result($result_tournament);
//read and save information from database
$query = "SELECT * FROM tms_servers WHERE id_tournament = ".$tourn_id;
$this->result_servers = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tms_stvs WHERE id_tournament = ".$tourn_id;
$this->result_stvs = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tms_matches WHERE id_tournament = ".$tourn_id;
$this->result_matches = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tms_teams_".$tourn_id." WHERE id_tournament = ".$tourn_id;
$this->result_teams = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
}
//*************************************************************************************
// Function draw
// Operation - Called to display a single elimination bracket
//*************************************************************************************
function draw() {
$total_rounds = log($this->tournament_size,2)+1; //total rounds
$row = array();
$col = array($row); //create a data type to hold our bracket information
//Generate a datastructure to hold all the information required to layout the bracket
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds; $i++) {
$round_matches = $this->getmatches($i);
$matches = pow(2,$total_rounds-$i); //calc how many matches for this round
$interval = pow(2,$i); // calc the interval for layout spacing
$offset = pow(2,$i-1); // each round is offset by a differnt amount to form the bracket pyramid
for($c = 1; $c <= ($this->tournament_size*2)+1; $c++) {
if ($c < $offset) { // blank space
$col[$i][$c] = 0;
} elseif ($c > (($this->tournament_size*2)+1)-$offset) { // blank space
$col[$i][$c] = 0;
} elseif ($c==$offset) {
if ($i==$total_rounds) { //No match but tournament winner
$col[$i][$c] = "Champion";
}else { //print a team here
$tmp_array=array_shift($round_matches);
$col[$i][$c] = $tmp_array['print_team'];
   }
} elseif ((($c-$offset) % $interval) == 0) { //print a team here
$tmp_array=array_shift($round_matches);
$col[$i][$c] = $tmp_array['print_team'];
} elseif ($c==($offset*2)) { //print match here
$col[$i][$c] = "Match".$tmp_array['id'];
} elseif ((($c-$offset*2) % ($interval*2)) == 0) { //print match here
$col[$i][$c] = "Match".$tmp_array['id'];
} else {
$col[$i][$c] = 0; // blank space
}
print("<br>");
}
// layout the bracket using html tables and the data struct created above: col
print("<table width='100%' border='5'>");
print("<tr>");
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds-1; $i++) {
print("<th>Round ".(string)$i."</th>");
}
print("</tr>");
for($c=1;$c<=($this->tournament_size*2);$c++) {
print("<tr>");
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds+1; $i++) {
if (strcmp(substr($col[$i][$c],0,5),"Match")==0) {
$tmp_array = $this->getmatch(substr($col[$i][$c],5));
$datetime = new DateTime($tmp_array['timestamp']);
print("<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFE4E1'><table><tr><td
align='center'>".$datetime->format("D, jS F Y gA")."</td></tr><tr><td     align='center'>stv - ".$this->getstvdetails($tmp_array['id_stv'])."</td></tr></table>    </td>");
} elseif (strcmp(substr($col[$i][$c],0,5),"Teams")==0) {
print("<td align='center' bgcolor='#dddddd'>".$this->getteamname(substr($col[$i]    [$c],5))."</td>");
} elseif ($col[$i][$c]) {
print("<td align='center' bgcolor='#dddddd'>".$col[$i][$c]."</td>");
} else {
print("<td height='40'></td>");
}
}
print("</tr>");
    }
print("</table>");
}
}
//*************************************************************************************
// Function getmatch
// Input - match_id
// Operation - Retrives all the information saved for the parsed match_id
//*************************************************************************************
function getmatch($match_id) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM tms_matches WHERE id = ".(string)$match_id;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
return $row;
}
    //*************************************************************************************
// Function getteamname
// Input - team_id
// Operation - Returns the name of the team with the parsed team ID
//***********************************************************************************    **
function getteamname($team_id) {
$query = "SELECT name FROM tms_teams_".(string)$this->tournament_id." WHERE id =     ".(string)$team_id;$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
return mysql_result($result, 0);
}
//*************************************************************************************
// Function getstvdetails
// Input - stv_id
// Operation - Returns the IP Address of the parsed stv id
//*************************************************************************************
function getstvdetails($stv_id) {
$query = "SELECT address FROM tms_stvs WHERE id = ".(string)$stv_id;
$result = mysql_query($query);
return mysql_result($result, 0);
}
//*************************************************************************************
// Function getmatches
// Input round_no
// Operation - Returns an array of all the matches for the parse round. The array is sorted by the position field.
//*************************************************************************************
function getmatches($round_no) {
$matches_avail = array();
$tmp_row = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM tms_matches WHERE id_tournament = ".$this->tournament_id."
AND round = ".(string)$round_no." ORDER BY position";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$tmp_row = $row;
if ($row['status'] == 1) {
$row = array_merge($row,array("print_team"=>"Winner of
".$row['id_match_parent_a']));
} else {
$row =
array_merge($row,array("print_team"=>"Teams".$row['id_team_a']));//team A
}
$matches_avail[] = $row;
$row = $tmp_row;
if ($row['status'] == 1) {
$row = array_merge($row,array("print_team"=>"Winner of
".$row['id_match_parent_b']));
} else {
$row =
array_merge($row,array("print_team"=>"Teams".$row['id_team_b']));//team B
}
$matches_avail[] = $row;
unset($tmp_row);
}return $matches_avail;
}
//*************************************************************************************
// destructor
// Operation - Frees memory held by SQL result sets
//*************************************************************************************
function __destruct() {
mysql_free_result($this->result_servers);
mysql_free_result($this->result_stvs);
mysql_free_result($this->result_matches);
mysql_free_result($this->result_teams);
mysql_close();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(-1)` and please indent your code, preferable with 4 spaces. This is completely unreadable.

Comment: Since you're starting out and all, I would suggestion moving away from mysql_* and use PDO for db connections.

Comment: As you have started you journey here on stackoverflow just read guidelines

Comment: You have the last `}` bracket without pair, try to remove it and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Now I'll repair that you can read.

Comment: If anyone would like some neatened up code, I have made it look better (and easier to read) here: http://pastebin.com/3gRK6Y6V

Comment: also learning and the PDO

Comment: Use an IDE to automatically see if your code is broken or not: I personally prefers Netbeans with PHP support, but you also have Eclipse, PHPStorm and many others...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any issues, but I cleaned up your code, maybe that will help someone find your issue.

```
<?php
    include('include.php');
    // PHP Class bracket
    // Bracket builder for GotGames
    // Author Benjamin Thomas
    // October 2009
    class bracket
            {
                    //Bring In Database Details From Include.PHP
                    var $username = DB_USER;
                    var $password = DB_PASS;
                    var $database = DB_NAME;
                    //Init Class Variables
                    var $tournament_name;
                    var $tournament_size;
                    var $tournament_format;
                    var $tournament_id;
                    var $result_servers;
                    var $result_stvs;
                    var $result_matches;
                    var $result_teams;
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    // schedule bracket
                    // Input - The tournament ID used to identify which tournament we are scheduling for
                    // Operation - This constructor reads the required information from the     databas and assigns the following class values:
                    // tournament_name;
                    // tournament_size;
                    // tournament_format;
                    // tournament_id;
                    // result_servers;
                    // result_stvs;
                    // result_matches;
                    // result_teams;
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    function bracket($tourn_id)
                            {
                                    //Save the Tournament ID
                                    $this->tournament_id = $tourn_id;
                                    //Collect All Required Information To Draw a Bracket
                                    mysql_connect('localhost', $this->username, $this->password);
                                    @mysql_select_db($this->database) or die("Unable to select database");
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tms_tournament WHERE id = " . $tourn_id;
                                    $result_tournament = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
                                    $row                     = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_tournament);
                                    $this->tournament_name   = $row['name'];
                                    $this->tournament_size   = $row['size'];
                                    $this->tournament_format = $row['format'];
                                    mysql_free_result($result_tournament);
                                    //read and save information from database
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tms_servers WHERE id_tournament = " . $tourn_id;
                                    $this->result_servers = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tms_stvs WHERE id_tournament = " . $tourn_id;
                                    $this->result_stvs = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tms_matches WHERE id_tournament = " . $tourn_id;
                                    $this->result_matches = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tms_teams_" . $tourn_id . " WHERE id_tournament = " . $tourn_id;
                                    $this->result_teams = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
                            }
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    // Function draw
                    // Operation - Called to display a single elimination bracket
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    function draw( )
                            {
                                    $total_rounds = log($this->tournament_size, 2) + 1;
                                    //total rounds
                                    $row          = array( );
                                    $col          = array(
                                                    $row
                                    );
                                    //create a data type to hold our bracket information
                                    //Generate a datastructure to hold all the information required to layout the bracket
                                    for($i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds; $i++)
                                            {
                                                    $round_matches = $this->getmatches($i);
                                                    $matches       = pow(2, $total_rounds - $i);
                                                    //calc how many matches for this round
                                                    $interval      = pow(2, $i);
                                                    // calc the interval for layout spacing
                                                    $offset        = pow(2, $i - 1);
                                                    // each round is offset by a differnt amount to form the bracket pyramid
                                                    for($c = 1; $c <= ($this->tournament_size * 2) + 1; $c++)
                                                            {
                                                                    if($c < $offset)
                                                                            {
                                                                                    // blank space
                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = 0;
                                                                            } //$c < $offset
                                                                    elseif($c > (($this->tournament_size * 2) + 1) - $offset)
                                                                            {
                                                                                    // blank space
                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = 0;
                                                                            } //$c > (($this->tournament_size * 2) + 1) - $offset
                                                                    elseif($c == $offset)
                                                                            {
                                                                                    if($i == $total_rounds)
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                    //No match but tournament winner
                                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = "Champion";
                                                                                            } //$i == $total_rounds
                                                                                    else
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                    //print a team here
                                                                                                    $tmp_array   = array_shift($round_matches);
                                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = $tmp_array['print_team'];
                                                                                            }
                                                                            } //$c == $offset
                                                                    elseif((($c - $offset) % $interval) == 0)
                                                                            {
                                                                                    //print a team here
                                                                                    $tmp_array   = array_shift($round_matches);
                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = $tmp_array['print_team'];
                                                                            } //(($c - $offset) % $interval) == 0
                                                                    elseif($c == ($offset * 2))
                                                                            {
                                                                                    //print match here
                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = "Match" . $tmp_array['id'];
                                                                            } //$c == ($offset * 2)
                                                                    elseif((($c - $offset * 2) % ($interval * 2)) == 0)
                                                                            {
                                                                                    //print match here
                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = "Match" . $tmp_array['id'];
                                                                            } //(($c - $offset * 2) % ($interval * 2)) == 0
                                                                    else
                                                                            {
                                                                                    $col[$i][$c] = 0;
                                                                                    // blank space
                                                                            }
                                                                    print("<br>");
                                                            } //$c = 1; $c <= ($this->tournament_size * 2) + 1; $c++
                                                    // layout the bracket using html tables and the data struct created above: col
                                                    print("<table width='100%' border='5'>");
                                                    print("<tr>");
                                                    for($i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds - 1; $i++)
                                                            {
                                                                    print("<th>Round " . (string) $i . "</th>");
                                                            } //$i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds - 1; $i++
                                                    print("</tr>");
                                                    for($c = 1; $c <= ($this->tournament_size * 2); $c++)
                                                            {
                                                                    print("<tr>");
                                                                    for($i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds + 1; $i++)
                                                                            {
                                                                                    if(strcmp(substr($col[$i][$c], 0, 5), "Match") == 0)
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                    $tmp_array = $this->getmatch(substr($col[$i][$c], 5));
                                                                                                    $datetime  = new DateTime($tmp_array['timestamp']);
                                                                                                    print("<td align='center' bgcolor='#FFE4E1'><table><tr><td
    align='center'>" . $datetime->format("D, jS F Y gA") . "</td></tr><tr><td     align='center'>stv - " . $this->getstvdetails($tmp_array['id_stv']) . "</td></tr></table>    </td>");
                                                                                            } //strcmp(substr($col[$i][$c], 0, 5), "Match") == 0
                                                                                    elseif(strcmp(substr($col[$i][$c], 0, 5), "Teams") == 0)
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                    print("<td align='center' bgcolor='#dddddd'>" . $this->getteamname(substr($col[$i][$c], 5)) . "</td>");
                                                                                            } //strcmp(substr($col[$i][$c], 0, 5), "Teams") == 0
                                                                                    elseif($col[$i][$c])
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                    print("<td align='center' bgcolor='#dddddd'>" . $col[$i][$c] . "</td>");
                                                                                            } //$col[$i][$c]
                                                                                    else
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                    print("<td height='40'></td>");
                                                                                            }
                                                                            } //$i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds + 1; $i++
                                                                    print("</tr>");
                                                            } //$c = 1; $c <= ($this->tournament_size * 2); $c++
                                                    print("</table>");
                                            } //$i = 1; $i <= $total_rounds; $i++
                            }
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    // Function getmatch
                    // Input - match_id
                    // Operation - Retrives all the information saved for the parsed match_id
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    function getmatch($match_id)
                            {
                                    $query  = "SELECT * FROM tms_matches WHERE id = " . (string) $match_id;
                                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                                    $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                                    mysql_free_result($result);
                                    return $row;
                            }
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    // Function getteamname
                    // Input - team_id
                    // Operation - Returns the name of the team with the parsed team ID
                    //***********************************************************************************    **
                    function getteamname($team_id)
                            {
                                    $query = "SELECT name FROM tms_teams_" . (string) $this->tournament_id . " WHERE id =     " . (string) $team_id;
                                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
                                    return mysql_result($result, 0);
                            }
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    // Function getstvdetails
                    // Input - stv_id
                    // Operation - Returns the IP Address of the parsed stv id
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    function getstvdetails($stv_id)
                            {
                                    $query  = "SELECT address FROM tms_stvs WHERE id = " . (string) $stv_id;
                                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                                    return mysql_result($result, 0);
                            }
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    // Function getmatches
                    // Input round_no
                    // Operation - Returns an array of all the matches for the parse round. The array is sorted by the position field.
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    function getmatches($round_no)
                            {
                                    $matches_avail = array( );
                                    $tmp_row       = array( );
                                    $query         = "SELECT * FROM tms_matches WHERE id_tournament = " . $this->tournament_id . "
    AND round = " . (string) $round_no . " ORDER BY position";
                                    $result        = mysql_query($query);
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                                            {
                                                    $tmp_row = $row;
                                                    if($row['status'] == 1)
                                                            {
                                                                    $row = array_merge($row, array(
                                                                                    "print_team" => "Winner of
    " . $row['id_match_parent_a']
                                                                    ));
                                                            } //$row['status'] == 1
                                                    else
                                                            {
                                                                    $row = array_merge($row, array(
                                                                                    "print_team" => "Teams" . $row['id_team_a']
                                                                    ));
                                                                    //team A
                                                            }
                                                    $matches_avail[ ] = $row;
                                                    $row              = $tmp_row;
                                                    if($row['status'] == 1)
                                                            {
                                                                    $row = array_merge($row, array(
                                                                                    "print_team" => "Winner of
    " . $row['id_match_parent_b']
                                                                    ));
                                                            } //$row['status'] == 1
                                                    else
                                                            {
                                                                    $row = array_merge($row, array(
                                                                                    "print_team" => "Teams" . $row['id_team_b']
                                                                    ));
                                                                    //team B
                                                            }
                                                    $matches_avail[ ] = $row;
                                                    unset($tmp_row);
                                            } //$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
                                    return $matches_avail;
                            }
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    // destructor
                    // Operation - Frees memory held by SQL result sets
                    //*************************************************************************************
                    function __destruct( )
                            {
                                    mysql_free_result($this->result_servers);
                                    mysql_free_result($this->result_stvs);
                                    mysql_free_result($this->result_matches);
                                    mysql_free_result($this->result_teams);
                                    mysql_close();
                            }
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks to arrangement. I tried put error reporting but still have wsod.

Comment: @IvanVukoja - The worst part is, its probably something very simple that we are all missing. I don't think its going to be a bracket issue at all. I would suggest doing what Lucha suggested and commenting out sections until you find the source, narrow that down for us then post what you come up with and maybe we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have the answer yet either but wanted to give you a hint of how you might start finding the issue.

When I get a whitescreen with no errors reported, I will start trying to narrow down the portion of code that contains the problem by commenting out LARGE amounts of code and then slowly un-commenting more and more of it to see exactly where the error occurs.

For example, I might comment out all of the functions inside the class.  Then I would slowly add back each function until the error happened.

This way, you will find a smaller portion of code to start taking apart.